# Django csrf_token in GET query

Tags: django, csrf

Is it necessary to add `{% csrf_token %}` in **GET** queries?

If I add it in GET, link starts to keep csrf_token **`?csrfmiddlewaretoken=`**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/):

> The first defense against CSRF attacks is to ensure that GET requests (and other ‘safe’ methods, as defined by 9.1.1 Safe Methods, HTTP 1.1, RFC 2616#section-9.1.1) are side-effect free. Requests via ‘unsafe’ methods, such as POST, PUT and DELETE, can then be protected by following the steps below.

So if you GET requests don't have any side effects, you **don't need** to include a CSRF Token.

Comment: GET requests should only retrieve data. So you should not save any data to the database (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616.html#section-9.1.1)

Comment: @worm2d: it shouldn't matter if a GET request is done 1 time or 1000 times, they shouldn't change anything at your backend (no database changes, no files changed, etc).

Comment: @RemcoGerlich so if my GET changes database should i use POST instead?

Comment: Yes, then you should use POST